# Convert.ToString() and .ToString() method in c#

Tags: c#

I know `Convert.ToString(obj)` handles null value and `ToString(obj)` doesn't handle null value.It means it will throw an error if the obj value is null.

```
ex:- 
object b = null;
textBox1.Text = b.ToString(); // It will throw a null reference exception because the object value is null.
```

It is correct and working as expected.
But,

```
ex:-
int? c = null;
textBox1.Text = c.ToString();
```

I tried in this way.
But in this case it is not throwing null reference exception error.
Why it is not throwing null reference exception error. Can anyone answer?

Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 9):

This is because `Nullable<int>` (which is the Type for which `int?` is shorthand) is a struct and therefore never `null`.

`int? c = null` is actually assigning `c.Value` to be `Null` rather than `c` itself, so `c.ToString()` is still a valid operation.

Answer (score 2):

`Nullable<T>` is a struct/value type. The actual nullable isn't null, but the value is. `object` is a class/reference type.